# Image not cache in create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, create-react-app

I know most of the image in website will be either memory or disk cache, but why all of my images is not cache everytime I refresh my page.

It is default in development server? or It cause by bug?

I create my react project with **create-react-app**

Comment: How do you know they aren't cached?

Comment: Hi Shmili, I check from the Google chrome network tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cache#view) to see how to check if your data is cached in google chrome.

If you don't see the images in cache check if you may have disabled caching for in your network tab (see image)

[image]

Comment: When I disabled the cache, the image required longer time to be load. Is this mean before this my images is cached?

Comment: @Wesley Loh That's, correct, you may have some other things blocking the page loading.